# Execute a function with parameters passed to an express server?

Tags: node.js, function, express

I want to call a function using the parameters passed to an express call. Here's an example tying to do a simple console.log inside a function called inside the app.get():

```
// server.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001

function processRequest(api_key, another_value) {
  console.log(api_key, another_value)
}

app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
  let api_key = req.query.api_key
  let another_value = req.query.another_value
  processRequest(api_key, another_value)
  res.json({api_key, another_value})
})

app.listen(port)
console.log("Started server")
```

and a simple test

```
const axios = require('axios')
function test() {
  axios.get('localhost:3001/api?api_key=testkey&another_value=anothervalue', res => console.log(res.data))
}
test()
```

I know i'm missing something simple here.
Thanks ya'll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `req.query.somevalue` to get query params from request.

`req.param` only works for URL params like `api/distance/:id`

Some from docs:

> (req.params) Checks route params, ex: /user/:id
>
> (req.query) Checks query string params, ex: ?id=12 Checks urlencoded body params

Comment: And i'm dumb because it was giving me a deprecation errors in my console that i didn't see... Thank Arpit!

Comment: Don't worry about it. It can happen in beginning.

Comment: That got me halfway. I am still finding problems calling a function with these params... can it even be done to call a function inside the ```app.get(...```? I need to update my example now

Comment: You can do whatever you want to do in app.get , call another function, do some calculations, return some response and many more

Comment: make sure your `processRequest()` is synchronous, or you need to use promises or callbacks.